# Is there an algorithm for this constrained Hypergraph optimization problem?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, hypergraph, sat

I'm currently developing an algorithm for computing knot coloring invariants and got to the following question:

Given a set $S$ and a certain hyper-graph $H \subseteq S^3 $, find a decomposition $S = S_1 \cup S_2$ with the constraint $H \subseteq S_1^3 \cup S_2^3$ and the goal to minimize $max(|S_1|,|S_2|)$.

I would like to know whether something of that sort has already been investigated.

I've included the tag SAT because I suspect there to be a connection between this problem and SAT, but I'm not an expert so I'm sorry if this tagging is regarded as spam.

Comment: $S^3$ means every hyperedge has 3 elements? And if so should the 3 elements be distinct?

Comment: @JohnMachacek yes, they should. also, order of elements matters and the set H can contain different orderings of the same elements.

Comment: Is this not the same as finding the connected components of the graph and grouping them in a balanced way? If that is the case then this is algorithmically easy.

Comment: @PuckRombach the concerning hypergraph could be completely connected so the solution might not consist of connected components. Also $A_1,A_2$ do not need to be disjoint. in fact it is very likely that they share elements.

Comment: I see! The word "decomposition" made me think of disjoint sets. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This is just intuition, but I think that what you are looking for is an optimal tree (path) decomposition with the constraint that you only want two bags. In other words, you're looking for an edge cut $[S,\overline{S}]$ that minimizes $|[S,\overline{S}]|+max(|[S,S]|,|[\overline{S},\overline{S}]|)$. I'm not sure how hard that is algorithmically.